# Firebase Cloud Functions : Failed to read credentials from file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Due to new Firebase Cloud Functions (version > 1.0). I only need to call

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Without any parameters.

However when I did like that then run firebase deploy --only functions , this error occurred :

> Failed to read credentials from file G:\projects\ANOTHER_PROJECT\ANOTHER_PROJECT.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\projects\ANOTHER_PROJECT\ANOTHER_PROJECT.json'

Comment: You're going to have to give more information about how you're running the code.  Please give the exact steps that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I ran the app by using firebase deploy --only functions

Comment: When doing the mandatory upgrade from Node 6 to Node 8 I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 35):

I found out the issue was that i had GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable defined which was pointing to json file which did not exist and i had long deleted.

I deleted the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  env variable. Restarted the terminal and then firebase deploy --only functions worked flawlessly.

Comment: How did you deleted it ?

Comment: Never mind, I just saw it's shell. Just need to use `unset VAR_NAME`

Answer (score 5):

If you have set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable right then just close the terminal and open a new one since the changes you have applied are not always taken into consideration in the current terminal

Comment: For local dev: this plus using a full path instead of relative path was the answer for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was adding the " in the path, I was using the windows terminal.

I hope it works for someone.

Comment: where did you add what exactly?